# Weird infinity polygons appearing

Tags: 3d-view

Recently I've been having some odd problems in Blender. Whenever I open a file and select an object, odd faces seem to appear that stretch to infinity.

This occurred on my old PC, both in Blender 2.79 and experimental versions, and now my brand new PC.

Whenever I select an object, nothing happens yet, but as soon as the camera is moved the polygons appear. They also appear for every object, and are different for each object.

[image: infinity polygons appear]

Any suggestions to remove this error would be greatly appreciated. 
Hardware specs: 
CPU Core 7900x
64GB Ram
Nvidia Titan X (Pascal)

Nvidia Driver 388.31
Latest official Blender release (2.79)

Thanks!

PS: It also appears when opening the default scene with just a cube and a camera.

Comment: try upading the drivers for the GPU

Comment: nice chainsaw anyway.

Comment: I'm already using the very latest nvidia drivers, as mentioned in the post. I don't think there are any newer ones available, at least not for the Titan X Pascal.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about "when this problem started"? I myself experienced hardship after update of Windows. It was solved by updating my GPU driver online. (as your driver is the latest, it might be off the point)

Comment: Sometimes the latest driver might be buggy,in that case search for an older driver and downgrade to it. Sometimes the latest driver is not yet compatible with the latest updates  for the operating system... not much to do there but wait for a fix...